# Datastax hadoop InvalidRequestException(why:You have not logged in)

Tags: mysql, hadoop, sqoop, datastax-enterprise

I have installed DataStax Enterprise "dse-4.0.1", but when I tried to do the demo per the below link

[http://www.datastax.com/docs/datastax_enterprise2.0/sqoop/sqoop_demo](http://www.datastax.com/docs/datastax%5fenterprise2.0/sqoop/sqoop%5fdemo), I am getting the below error, can anybody please help me with the issue, I am facing, log file attached for your reference.

```
[root@chbslx0624 bin]# ./dse sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/npa_nxx_demo  --username root  --password poc123 --table npa_nxx  --target-dir /npa_nxx
14/04/14 10:44:14 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
14/04/14 10:44:14 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
14/04/14 10:44:14 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
14/04/14 10:44:14 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `npa_nxx` AS t LIMIT 1
14/04/14 10:44:14 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `npa_nxx` AS t LIMIT 1
14/04/14 10:44:14 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_HOME is /opt/cassandra/dse-4.0.1/resources/hadoop/bin/..
Note: /tmp/sqoop-root/compile/b0fc8093d30c07f252da42678679e461/npa_nxx.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
14/04/14 10:44:15 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-root/compile/b0fc8093d30c07f252da42678679e461/npa_nxx.jar
14/04/14 10:44:15 WARN manager.MySQLManager: It looks like you are importing from mysql.
14/04/14 10:44:15 WARN manager.MySQLManager: This transfer can be faster! Use the --direct
14/04/14 10:44:15 WARN manager.MySQLManager: option to exercise a MySQL-specific fast path.
14/04/14 10:44:15 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Setting zero DATETIME behavior to convertToNull (mysql)
14/04/14 10:44:15 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning import of npa_nxx
14/04/14 10:44:17 INFO snitch.Workload: Setting my workload to Cassandra
14/04/14 10:44:18 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:root cause:java.io.IOException: InvalidRequestException(why:You have not logged in)
14/04/14 10:44:18 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: InvalidRequestException(why:You have not logged in)
        at com.datastax.bdp.util.CassandraProxyClient.initialize(CassandraProxyClient.java:453)
        at com.datastax.bdp.util.CassandraProxyClient.<init>(CassandraProxyClient.java:376)
        at com.datastax.bdp.util.CassandraProxyClient.newProxyConnection(CassandraProxyClient.java:259)
        at com.datastax.bdp.util.CassandraProxyClient.newProxyConnection(CassandraProxyClient.java:306)
        at com.datastax.bdp.hadoop.cfs.CassandraFileSystemThriftStore.initialize(CassandraFileSystemThriftStore.java:230)
        at com.datastax.bdp.hadoop.cfs.CassandraFileSystem.initialize(CassandraFileSystem.java:73)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1386)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:66)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1404)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:254)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:187)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles.getStagingDir(JobSubmissionFiles.java:97)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:856)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:850)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:850)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:500)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:530)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runJob(ImportJobBase.java:141)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:202)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.importTable(SqlManager.java:475)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager.importTable(MySQLManager.java:108)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:403)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:476)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:145)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:181)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:220)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:229)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:238)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:57)
Caused by: InvalidRequestException(why:You have not logged in)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$describe_keyspaces_result$describe_keyspaces_resultStandardScheme.read(Cassandra.java:31961)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$describe_keyspaces_result$describe_keyspaces_resultStandardScheme.read(Cassandra.java:31928)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$describe_keyspaces_result.read(Cassandra.java:31870)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_describe_keyspaces(Cassandra.java:1181)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.describe_keyspaces(Cassandra.java:1169)
        at com.datastax.bdp.util.CassandraProxyClient.initialize(CassandraProxyClient.java:425)
        ... 32 more
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have another local running Cassandra node which is username/password enable. You can follow the latest document, and start DSE as -t then run the import script.